# Trouble gathering JSON from DB and recieving it on Xamarin Forms

Tags: rest, http, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am following a document on how to recieve data from a database-site where I have my own API-key that is needed to get it out. However I have trouble reaching the JSONdata.

These are the documents I follow.

https://cbis-rest-api.citybreak.com/v1/swagger/ui/index

https://visit.github.io/api-doc/

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
static public class myData
{
    static string apiKey = "myApiKeyNumber";
    static string apiApp = "application/json";

    static public async Task<JObject> testing()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient();

        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", apiKey);
        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", apiApp);

        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync("https://cbis-rest-api.citybreak.com/v1/api/raw/product/");
        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(resultString);

        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(resultString);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonResult);

    }
}
```

And when I want to work with it:

```
async void loadData()
    {
        var getInfo = await phpApi.testing();

        if (getInfo == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("no data");
        }
        else {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data");
        }

    }
```

I think that the httpadress i entered in my JObject task must be wrong because when I run this code I get the crash: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path ", line 0, position 0.".

And when i run the "resultString" System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(resultString); in the log i get this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-/W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtm1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
    <style type="text/css">`
```

Which means that the http (https://cbis-rest-api.citybreak.com/v1/api/raw/product/) does not have the json.
When I look at the documents i think that i am following the correct instruction however so i am a bit confused.

Any help, guidance would be very appreciated. I am not used to working with databases so i appreciate the help a lot!

UPDATED:

```
  static public class myData
{
    static string apiKey = "myApiKeyNumber";
    static string apiApp = "application/json";

    static public async Task<JObject> testing()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient();

        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", apiKey);
        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", apiApp);

        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync("https://cbis-rest-api.citybreak.com/v1/api/raw/product/getpaged/1");
        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(resultString);


        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(resultString);
        return jsonResult;

    }
}
```

With this code I get the error "Error reading JObject from JsonReader, Path ", line 0, position 0", and i get nothing in the log from the resultString which means that there is no JSON there? I try with many different ID's but with same result. I do not quite know where i find the id of the data either.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the API clearly states that the /raw/product/ call needs an {Id} property for the Id of the product you wish to retreive.

To get a *list* of products, use /raw/product/getpaged/
That still requires a parameter, in this case {pagesize}, which means you still need to add a parameter on how many products per page you wish to retreive.

A correct call would be something like "/raw/product/getpaged/10"

You can verify in your browser that trying to "GET" just /raw/product/ will result in the 404 error that you are seeing in your code.
While adding a parameter for the ID result in an "unauthorized access" error, as I do not have your key and secret.

Comment: Okok. I have only worked with phpmyadmin before and i dont think this database system has a similiar setup so i am not sure where i can find the id that i need. When I use my code and change the httpadress to your suggested one instead I still get the  "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path ", line 0, position 0." error. I tried with different ID's but i keep getting the same error.

Comment: i am an intern at a small company and this is the system where they store their data so therefor i am very unsure how it works at the moment and they do not know much either

Comment: The error ""Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path "" simply comes from the http response containing an html error page which you are trying to parse as if it was a json object. Please run System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(resultString); again and show the entire error message you are getting now. Also please include the actual url you are calling now

Comment: Check the updated code in the end of my post, with that code I get the error "Error reading JObject from JsonReader, Path ", line 0, position 0", and i get nothing in the log from the resultString which means that there is no json there maybe?

Comment: This most likely means you did not properly authorize your request, but without further info it is hard to say. Try using Postman or any other free tool for testing http calls and recreate the call there (add the api key and accept headers, use the same url as in your current code). Then see what status code comes back and what content if any.  https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Ok! I will check it out and see if i make any progress. Thanks for the link